# get the first (or n'th) element in a jq json parsing

Tags: json, jq

I can get the 1st element in a json inside []

```
$ echo '[{"a":"x", "b":true}, {"a":"XML", "b":false}]' | jq '.[1]'
{
  "a": "XML",
  "b": false
}
```

But if the json is already disassembled (for instance, after filtering entries using 'select'), how can I choose a single entry and avoid the error seen here?

```
$ echo '[{"a":"x", "b":true}, {"a":"x", "b":false},{"a":"XML", "b":false}]' | jq '.[] | select( .a == "x")'
{
  "a": "x",
  "b": true
}
{
  "a": "x",
  "b": false
}
$ echo '[{"a":"x", "b":true}, {"a":"x", "b":false},{"a":"XML", "b":false}]' | jq '.[] | select( .a == "x") | .[1]'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index object with number
```

Comment: `'.[1]'` actually gets the second element.  `'.[0]'` will get you the first.  Javascript's arrays are zero-based.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can wrap the results from `select` in an array:

```
jq '[.[]|select(.a=="x")][0]' your.json
```

Output:

```
{
  "a": "x",
  "b": false
}
```

Answer (score 45):

jq also provides [`first/0`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/jq-1.6/src/builtin.jq#L178), [`last/0`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/jq-1.6/src/builtin.jq#L179), [`nth/1`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/jq-1.6/src/builtin.jq#L180) so in this case the filter

```
  ( map(select(.a == "x")) | first  )
, ( map(select(.a == "x")) | last   ) 
, ( map(select(.a == "x")) | nth(1) )
```

produces

```
{
  "a": "x",
  "b": true
}
{
  "a": "x",
  "b": false
}
{
  "a": "x",
  "b": false
}
```

Additional streaming forms ['first/1'](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/jq-1.6/src/builtin.jq#L175), ['last/1'](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/jq-1.6/src/builtin.jq#L176) and ['nth/2'](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/jq-1.6/src/builtin.jq#L177) are also available so with this data

```
  ( first(.[]  | select(.a == "x")) )   
, ( last(.[]   | select(.a == "x")) )
, ( nth(1; .[] | select(.a == "x")) )
```

produces

```
{
  "a": "x",
  "b": true
}
{
  "a": "x",
  "b": false
}
{
  "a": "x",
  "b": false
}
```

Comment: neat. How can I also do a jq request to retrieve the number of entries?

Comment: Would suggest the [length](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#length) builtin or perhaps `reduce .[] as $x (0;.+1)`

Answer (score 26):

Many of the previous answers work by avoiding to create a stream of objects in the first place. But what if you are *starting* with a stream of objects—for example JSON-formatted application logs? If your input file (or stream) has multiple objects in it, all you need to do to choose a single entry from a stream of independent objects is to use the `--slurp` option (or `-s` for the short form):

> ```
>    o   --slurp/-s:
>
>        Instead of running the filter for each JSON object in the input, read 
>        the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once.
> ```

Then you can just index into the array.  For example, to get second item (with index 1):

```
jq --slurp '.[1]'
```

Putting this together with your original question, where you want to select that item from a stream:

```
echo '{"a":"x", "b":true} {"a":"XML", "b":false}' | jq --slurp '.[1]'
```

which results in this output:

```
{
  "a": "XML",
  "b": false
}
```

This method does, of course, read the entire input into memory. For an approach that avoids this problem, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73559001/2562319) from Martin von Wittich.

Comment: *Thank you*, all other answers yielded some variation of `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index object with number` but this worked like a charm.

Comment: This is great, this is exactly what I needed; piping output from `gunzip -c` to `jq`

Answer (score 7):

use `map`

```
cat raw.json|jq -r -c 'map(select(.a=="x"))|.[1]'
```

`map` receives a **filter** to filter an array.

this command

```
cat raw.json|jq -r -c 'map(select(.a=="x"))'
```

give the middle result

> ```
> [{"a":"x","b":true},{"a":"x","b":false}]
> ```

`.[1]` take the first element

Answer (score 1):

I have the same scenario as jbyler - I want to parse N lines of a JSON log, where each line is a single object:

```
host ~ # head /var/log/nginx/access.log.json | cut -c 1-80 
{"remote_addr":"127.0.0.1","remote_port":"47700","time_iso8601":"2022-08-31T00:0
{"remote_addr":"127.0.0.1","remote_port":"35576","time_iso8601":"2022-08-31T00:0
{"remote_addr":"127.0.0.1","remote_port":"47708","time_iso8601":"2022-08-31T00:0
{"remote_addr":"127.0.0.1","remote_port":"52974","time_iso8601":"2022-08-31T00:0
{"remote_addr":"127.0.0.1","remote_port":"52976","time_iso8601":"2022-08-31T00:0
{"remote_addr":"127.0.0.1","remote_port":"51414","time_iso8601":"2022-08-31T00:0
{"remote_addr":"127.0.0.1","remote_port":"41942","time_iso8601":"2022-08-31T00:1
{"remote_addr":"127.0.0.1","remote_port":"41946","time_iso8601":"2022-08-31T00:1
{"remote_addr":"127.0.0.1","remote_port":"37982","time_iso8601":"2022-08-31T00:1
{"remote_addr":"127.0.0.1","remote_port":"56602","time_iso8601":"2022-08-31T00:1
```

I do not like the `--slurp` solution because this will cause `jq` to read the entire file, when I might only be interested in the first N lines.

The solution for this seems to be the [`input`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#input) function combined with `jq -n`, which reads a single input object:

```
host ~ # cat /var/log/nginx/access.log.json | jq -r -n 'input | [.remote_addr, .remote_port, .time_iso8601] | @tsv' 
127.0.0.1       47700   2022-08-31T00:02:53+02:00
```

Combined with [`range`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#range(upto),range(from;upto)range(from;upto;by)), I can use it to read up to N input objects:

```
host ~ # cat /var/log/nginx/access.log.json | jq -r -n 'range(10) as $i | input | [.remote_addr, .remote_port, .time_iso8601] | @tsv'
127.0.0.1       47700   2022-08-31T00:02:53+02:00
127.0.0.1       35576   2022-08-31T00:02:53+02:00
127.0.0.1       47708   2022-08-31T00:02:53+02:00
127.0.0.1       52974   2022-08-31T00:07:53+02:00
127.0.0.1       52976   2022-08-31T00:07:53+02:00
127.0.0.1       51414   2022-08-31T00:07:58+02:00
127.0.0.1       41942   2022-08-31T00:12:53+02:00
127.0.0.1       41946   2022-08-31T00:12:53+02:00
127.0.0.1       37982   2022-08-31T00:13:03+02:00
127.0.0.1       56602   2022-08-31T00:17:53+02:00
```

Be careful with wrapping this into an array though - doing it wrong will cause `jq` to *reevaluate* the `[range(10) as $i | input]` expression, so here I'm not getting elements `[0, 1, 2]`, but `[0, 11, 22]`:

```
# WRONG, DON'T DO THIS
host ~ # cat /var/log/nginx/access.log.json | jq -r -n '[range(10) as $i | input][0,1,2] | [.remote_addr, .remote_port, .time_iso8601] | @tsv'
127.0.0.1       47700   2022-08-31T00:02:53+02:00
127.0.0.1       59784   2022-08-31T00:18:22+02:00
127.0.0.1       34316   2022-08-31T00:37:53+02:00
```

To safely access the same array multiple times, you need to have a pipe in between:

```
host ~ # cat /var/log/nginx/access.log.json | jq -r -n '[range(10) as $i | input] | .[0,1,2] | [.remote_addr, .remote_port, .time_iso8601] | @tsv'
127.0.0.1       47700   2022-08-31T00:02:53+02:00
127.0.0.1       35576   2022-08-31T00:02:53+02:00
127.0.0.1       47708   2022-08-31T00:02:53+02:00
```

This way, you can take up to N objects from the input file, and then extract arbitrary ones from this selection.