# First occurrence of element in json dictionary with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have following json :

```json
$ echo '{ "format_id": "250" }{ "format_id": "18" }{ "format_id": "140" }{ "format_id": "18" }{ "format_id": "244" }' | jq .
{
  "format_id": "250"
}
{
  "format_id": "18"
}
{
  "format_id": "140"
}
{
  "format_id": "18"
}
{
  "format_id": "244"
}
```

I managed to extract the `format_id`s for which it equals to "18" :

```json
$ echo '{ "format_id": "250" }{ "format_id": "18" }{ "format_id": "140" }{ "format_id": "18" }{ "format_id": "244" }' | jq -r 'select(.format_id=="18")'
{
  "format_id": "18"
}
{
  "format_id": "18"
}
```

I want to extract out of that the 1st occurrence of `format_id`.

So I tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38500610/5649639) but none of them worked because I guess they need to be adapted to my input data somehow :

```json
$ echo '{ "format_id": "18" }{ "format_id": "18" }' | jq '[.[]|select(.format_id)][0]'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "format_id"
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "format_id"
$ echo '{ "format_id": "18" }{ "format_id": "18" }' | jq '( map(select(.format_id)) | first  )'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "format_id"
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "format_id"
$ echo '{ "format_id": "18" }{ "format_id": "18" }' | jq '( first(.[]  | select(.format_id)) )'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "format_id"
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "format_id"
$ echo '{ "format_id": "18" }{ "format_id": "18" }' | jq 'map(select(.format_id))|.[0]'        
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "format_id"
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "format_id"
```

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your jq has `inputs` then it would be best to use it in conjunction with the -n command-line option and the following jq filter:

```
first(inputs | select(.format_id =="18"))
```

### If your jq does not have `inputs`

... then you'd have to use the -s command-line option, e.g. with the following filter:

```
first(.[] | select(.format_id =="18"))
```

Here, using `inputs` is preferable as it requires less RAM.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'd tried this `first(select(.format_id =="18"))` but it didn't work. I wish I understood `jq` a little more. I'd read the official tutorial and manual but it does not say much about `inputs` (only two lines of text without a `inputs` use case example). There are many tutorials on the internet. I really don't know which to read. I'd read some but none that really gave me a better `jg` understanding when it comes to deal with dictionary only data. Where can I find "very good" `jq` tutorial according to you ?

Comment: @SebMa You ran it like `jq -n 'first(select(.format_id =="18"))' file.json`, right?

Comment: SebMa - As it happens, the introduction I wrote some time ago does have a whole section devoted to `inputs`: https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq#on-the-importance-of-inputs

Comment: @oguzismail Nope, I didn't use `jq -n` but `jq`

Comment: @peak Thanks again for your help. Can you please update your answer by prefixing `...| jq -n '` to your first command and `...| jq -s '` to the second so that it would be more explicit for other `jq` rookies like me :)
BTW : Can you also add your `inputs` documentation link to your answer ?
But if you don't have the time, please tell me and I'll do it right away.