# How to get the first element of a array?

Tags: bash, shell, pm2

The command `pm2 id <name>`  returns an array (e.g `[2]`), how would I get the first element from the array?
I want to save the output in `APP_ID=$(pm2 id <name>)` so `APP_ID` ends up being `2`

Comment: It'd help to mention what format the array is in. It's a JS array, right? And it's JSON-compatible? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Please add output of `pm2 id <name>` to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `pm2`, but if the array is JSON-compatible (which it looks like it is), you can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/#), for example:

```
$ echo '[2]' | jq '.[0]'
2
$ echo '[3, 2]' | jq '.[0]'
3
```

Here's a related question with some other methods: [get the first (or n'th) element in a jq json parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38500363/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

If the output is "[2]", tahts a string, not an array. You just need to cut the first and last character off.

```bash
APP_ID=$(pm2 id <name>)
APP_ID=${APP_ID:1: -1}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem very helpful as clearly the output `[2]` is only a singleton, which doesn't seem the general case (otherwise the OP would have specified that)...